# iPhone App: Reloading Webview with Tabs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application, I want to have a Webview and a button on the bottom bar (should it be a tab, bar button, or navigation item?).

In this Webview, it will display a web page of user information. For example, user profiles on a website.

Example URL: http://myusersite.com?uid=1

What I am trying to accomplish is allow the application user to press the bottom button and have it:

A) Increase the uid++, so the next value would be uid=2
B) Reload the page in that window with the information from user 2.

How can I refresh the page and have a button that sets a variable to be included in a URL for the refreshed page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need any of the navigation items you mentioned.

What you need is a simple blank view with a button in its buttom and a UIWebView.
you also need a counter.

when the button clicks, increase the counter by one and rebuild the url:

```
- (void)refreshPage{

counter = counter +1;
NSString *urlAddress =
[NSString stringWithFormat: http://myusersite.com?uid=%@", counter];

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

Comment: The line NSSTring *urlAddress=.... gives an objc_msgsend error that breaks the program.